Как добавить строчку кода через x64dbg?
начал только работать с masm64 и x64dbg, подскажите, как в уже готовый exe файл, открытый через x64dbg, добавить строчку кода?
У меня в примере 5 делим на 2, нужно бы добавить что бы 5 мы поделили на 2 и добавили к результату 4.

Нашел алгоритм, через команду jmp, но не могу понять как применить на моем примере, как и когда использовать эту команду?


Найти "пустое место", куда можно вставить код (вот в вашем коде можно использовать пространство ниже call - там пустое место на самом деле, а не команды add). Какую-то строку заменяете на переход на это место. На новом месте пишем затертую строку и строку, которую нужно добавить и переход обратно. Часто удобно использовать call вместо jmp, тогда обратный переход делается просто через ret.

Хотя, тут можно вообще call передвинуть ниже, а выше добавить нужную команду.

К примеру:

берете вот этот кусок
mox rax, 5
mov rcx, 2
div rcx

перемещаете на новое место

вместо него пишете переход на это новое место

дописываете что надо на новом месте

а в конце делаете переход обратно на продолжение старого кода
-> mov rcx, 0


